Correct pronoun in reported speech
What is the correct reported speech for

She said to me, "When are we going to leave?"

Is it:

A) She asked me when they were going to leave.
B) She asked me when we were going to leave.

Can both answers be correct depending on the circumstances?

Yes, depending on whether the speaker is among the people planning to leave.

Why would the person reporting her question have known more about when she and her party were going to leave than she herself knew?  A) is not impossible but it is rather far-fetched as a reported version of "When are we going to leave?" Maybe the person reporting the question is Phil Keoghan.

@TimR :- There can be various cases where the person reporting is the decision maker.  Case 1 : A couple went to a party. It is getting late but the husband is still enjoying, so the wife goes and asks him. Case 2: The husband has promised to drive his family from London to Scotland by car. So in the morning the wife asks so that she could plan.

@JamesMathai   My underlying point is that questions that ask us to think of a context where a particular formulation might make reasonable sense are more word puzzles than questions about how to express a particular thing.  Why would the husband be telling another person what his wife asked him?  I suppose he could be talking to a marriage counselor.

@TimR : In our story, the next morning his friends tell him, "Why did you leave? We had such a good time after you left." Husband: "She asked me when we were going to leave?"


She said to me, "When are we going to leave?"


A) She asked me when they were going to leave.
B) She asked me when we were going to leave.

Edit
Collins Dictionary third section, sense (1) says the pronoun we refers to

the speaker or writer and another or others, sometimes including those addressed

Hence both (A) and (B) are possible, and only context can determine it.

Why is "the speaker or writer and another or others, sometimes including those addressed" formatted as a quote? Please provide the source if it's a quote, or remove the formatting.

Thanks, @gotube.  I have added the link.

@SeowjoohengSingapore : Thank you for the answer. You explained what is meant by 'we' correctly.
